# Javascript array incorrect loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

maybe I'm forgetting something, but I can not loop over and array inside an object.

I have this:

```
    var myCategory = {
        id: snapshot.id,
        name: category.name,
        order: category.order,
        status: category.status,
        menuOptions:[]
    }
```

Then I push options

```
myCategory.menuOptions.push(menuOption);
```

then I log myCategory and get this:

```
{id: 'K1VXbeGo3qivFAV61x5P2', name: 'Combos', order: 1, status: 'A', menuOptions: Array(0)}
id: "K1VXbeGo3qivFAV61x5P2"
menuOptions: Array(2)
0: {id: 'LFtAWpu9iKUY0fjXvuji', categoryId: 'K1VXbeGo3qivFAV61x5P2', name: 'Escoge tu salsa', order: 1, OptionsOnItemInCart: undefined, …}
1: {id: 'zp5AwxU04XhhVcGjep1F', categoryId: 'K1VXbeGo3qivFAV61x5P2', name: 'Adicionales', order: 1, OptionsOnItemInCart: undefined, …}
length: 2
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
name: "Combos"
order: 1
status: "A"
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Now I try to loop over myCategory.menuOptions but I can not,
this: `Array.isArray( category.menuOptions)` give me a true,

but when I call `category.menuOptions.length` return 0.

Any idea?
thanks.

Comment: Can you update the question to include a runnable code snippet which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I think I know what this is: you're pushing options into the array asynchronously, but trying to access its length without waiting for that async function to complete, aren't you?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol yes; I'm pushing the options in aasync func I use await to get the MyCategory and then try to loop options.